# ¿Como corregir no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , Laravel y AngularJS?

Tags: laravel, angularjs

Estoy realizando un formulario para creación de usuarios, en dicho formulario mando a guardar una foto del usuario.
Tengo realizdo el metodo en Laravel y al testear la ruta para la creación de usuario y con imagen en postman no me genera ningun problema, se crea el registro sin inconvenientes.
El detalle que tengo es cuando ya utilizo este metodo en AngularJS
Esta es la función en angularjs:

```
$scope.btnCrearUsuario = function(item) {
            $scope.item = item;
            var fd = new FormData();
            var file = item.avatar;
            fd.append('avatar',file);
            fd.append('nombre', item.nombre);
            fd.append('apellido',item.apellido);
            fd.append('usuario', item.usuario);
            fd.append('password',item.password);
            fd.append('idtipousuario', item.idtipousuario);
            fd.append('correo', item.correo);
            fd.append('telefono', item.telefono);
            fd.append('estado', item.estado);

             $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: server+'ws/usuarios',
                data: fd,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false},
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            }).then( function() {
                console.log('success');
            }, function() {
                console.log('failure');
            });
        }
```

Me da el siguiente error en consola:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma tengo realizado el metodo en laravel:

```
 public function updateImage(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try 
        {
            $nombre = "";
            if ($request->hasFile("avatar")){
                $temp    = $request->file('avatar');
                $destino = public_path()."\avatars";
                $nombre  = str_random(6).$temp->getClientOriginalName();
                $subio   = $temp->move($destino, $nombre);
                 if(!$subio)
                     throw new \Exception('No se pudo subir la foto');
            }
                $editarRegistro = \DB::transaction(function() use ($request, $id, $nombre)
                {
                    $registro = Usuarios::find($id);
                    if (! $registro) 
                    {
                      throw new \Exception("No existe el registro");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $registro->avatar        = $nombre != "" ? $nombre : $registro->avatar;
                        $registro->nombre        = $request->input('nombre', $registro->nombre);
                        $registro->apellido      = $request->input('apellido', $registro->apellido);
                        $registro->usuario       = $request->input('usuario', $registro->usuario);
                        if ($request->has('password') || $request->input('password') !="")
                            $registro->password = \Hash::make($request->input('password')); 
                        $registro->idtipousuario = $request->input('idtipousuario', $registro->idtipousuario);
                        $registro->correo        = $request->input('correo', $registro->correo);
                        $registro->telefono      = $request->input('telefono', $registro->telefono);
                        $registro->estado        = $request->input('estado', $registro->estado);
                        $registro->save();
                        return $registro;
                    }
                });
                    $statusCode     = 200;
                    $this->records  = $editarRegistro;
                    $this->message  = "Se edito correctamente el registro";
                    $this->result   = true;

        } 
        catch (\Exception $e) 
        {
          $statusCode       = 200;
          $this->message    = env('APP_DEBUG')?$e->getMessage():"El registro no se edito";
          $this->result     = false;   
        }
        finally
        {
            $response =
            [
                'message'   => $this->message,
                'result'    => $this->result,
                'records'   => $this->records
            ];
                return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
        }
    }
```

De antemano muy agradecido por el apoyo.

Comment: `192.168.1.5` no es el mismo origen que `localhost` (aunque sea la misma ip) tendrías que armar un middleware que setee los headers , hay un par de pistas aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39429462/1423096

Comment: En el servidor donde tengas tu web, habrá un archivo en la raiz con el nombre `.htaccess`. Edítalo y añade esta línea al final `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`. Después guarda y vuelve a probar a enviar los datos.

Comment: Estás digitando mal en la vista, el nombre de la función updateImage

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar las cabeceras correspondientes a la petición antes de ser procesada o especificarlas en el cliente. Puedes agregarlas a la petición creando un middleware y agregar lo siguiente:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

o por el contrario, te recomiendo esta libreria de barryvdh que se encargará de CORS por ti.[Utilizar esta librería](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)